# I want two tables calculate

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I  want to add and calculate using data from 2 tables.

The results I want are as follows.
[image]

However, if I send a query as follows:

> SELECT COUNT(IF(treatment_fees_check_division = 'test',
> treatment_fees_check_division, NULL)) AS COUNT,  SUM(CASE WHEN
> treatment_fees_check_division = 'test' THEN treatment_fees_difference
> END) + SUM(advenced_amount) AS if_treatment_fees_check_division,
> SUM(advenced_amount) AS sum_init_amount FROM ( SELECT
> treatment_fees_check_division, treatment_fees_difference,
> advenced_amount FROM hospital_payment_data, advenced_payment WHERE
> hospital_payment_data.id = advenced_payment.chart_num ) AS a

These results occur.

[image]

create table of hospital_payment_data and data

```
  CREATE TABLE `hospital_payment_data` (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
        `chart_num` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
        `chart_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `visit` DATE NOT NULL,
        `non_payment_sales` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `total_medical_bills` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `total_amount` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `amount_asked` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `medical_bills_payment` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `personal_liability_amount` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `non_payment` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `insurance_division` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `division` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `cash_amount_received` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `cash_receipt` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `cash_receipt_non_payment` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `cash_receipt_payment` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `card_amount_received` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `card_non_payment` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `card_payment` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `medical_bills_check` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `medical_bills_check_modify` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
        `treatment_fees_difference` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `init_amount` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `treatment_fees_check_division` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
        `treatment_fees_check` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `treatment_fees_check_modify` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
        `treatment_fees_check_memo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
    COLLATE='euckr_korean_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=18
    ;
```

[image]

create table of advenced_payment and data

```
CREATE TABLE `advenced_payment` (`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`chart_num` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`chart_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`advenced_amount` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `chart_num` (`chart_num`)) COLLATE='euckr_korean_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

[image]

How do fix my query??

Answer (score 0):

You have numerous issues with you query.  This won't fix your problems, but I recommend writing it as:

```
SELECT SUM(hpd.treatment_fees_check_division = 'test') AS COUNT,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN hpd.treatment_fees_check_division = 'test' THEN hpd.treatment_fees_difference END) +
        SUM(advenced_amount)
       ) AS if_treatment_fees_check_division,
       SUM(advenced_amount) AS sum_init_amount
FROM hospital_payment_data hpd JOIN
     advanced_payment ap
     ON hpd.id = ap.chart_num;
```

This simplifies and fixes some issues:

- The `JOIN` uses proper, explicit, **standard**, readable syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- The subquery is utterly unnecessary and probably adversely affects performance.
- All tables have table aliases.
- All column references are qualified.
- The condition count is much simplified using `sum(<boolean>)`.

I note that `treatment_fees_difference` is a string, yet you are using `SUM()`.  That is really, really bad.

In any case, your problem, is that one of the tables has multiple rows.  It is hard to know which one but my guess is `advanced_payment`.  The solution is to preaggregate before the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT SUM(hpd.treatment_fees_check_division = 'test') AS COUNT,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN hpd.treatment_fees_check_division = 'test' THEN hpd.treatment_fees_difference END) +
        SUM(ap.sum_init_amount)
       ) AS if_treatment_fees_check_division,
       SUM(ap.sum_init_amount) AS sum_init_amount
FROM hospital_payment_data hpd JOIN
     (SELECT ap.chart_num, COUNT(*) as cnt, SUM(advenced_amount) as sum_init_amount
      FROM advanced_payment ap
      GROUP BY ap.chart_num
     ) ap
     ON hpd.id = ap.chart_num;
```